# Are nested format specifications legal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Recently, I came across the following oddity.  Nesting `{}`-enclosed format fields seems to work in both Python 2.7 and 3.6, but I can't find anything in the docs to say that should be so.  For example, I get the following result on both 3.6 and 2.7:

```
>>> '{:{}.{}f}'.format(27.5, 6, 2)
' 27.50'
```

Has anyone seen this before, and is it an intended feature?  Normally, I'd dismiss this as an implementation quirk, and maybe report it as a bug. Two things, though:  Python docs don't always put all the information in the place I'd look for it, and this is a Very Nice Feature to have.

Comment: There is explicit mention of the behaviour in PEP 3101 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#format-specifiers. Nice feature thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yes, they are legal (and work).

Comment: BTW, nested formatting also works in Python 3.6+ f-strings. There's even a way to do dynamic formatting with the old `%` style string interpolation using `*`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is documented at the end of the introduction to the ["Format String Syntax"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) section:

> A *format_spec* field can also include nested replacement fields within it. These nested replacement fields may contain a field name, conversion flag and format specification, but deeper nesting is not allowed. The replacement fields within the format_spec are substituted before the *format_spec* string is interpreted. This allows the formatting of a value to be dynamically specified.

Some examples of this feature can also be found at the end of the ["Format examples"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) section, such as:

```
>>> for align, text in zip('<^>', ['left', 'center', 'right']):
...     '{0:{fill}{align}16}'.format(text, fill=align, align=align)
...
'left<<<<<<<<<<<<'
'^^^^^center^^^^^'
'>>>>>>>>>>>right'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I *know* I read page in both the 2.7 and 3.x docs and missed that paragraph both times.